# About DJI Zenmuse L1 and its corresponding visible light images

Tags: sdk

"When the DJI Zenmuse L1 LiDAR is in operation, it captures visible light images simultaneously with LiDAR point cloud data. However, the LiDAR point cloud is formed as a single integrated point cloud file after capture, while the camera images are captured one by one as JPG images.
How can I obtain LiDAR data that corresponds to the visible light images? In other words, how can I ensure that there is LiDAR data corresponding to each individual visible light image (as shown in the example below)?"

"I hope you can provide me with specific step-by-step instructions and a clear methodology, preferably with visual aids for explanation."